# findstr not found string into the utf-8 file

Tags: windows, utf-8, character-encoding, utf, findstr

I need to finder script on the windows command line. I will call the command in a PHP `exec()` function.

I am using `findstr` command. But this command not working on Turkish Character.  Like this

```
findstr /s /r /n /i /C:Türkçe C:\wamp\www\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\text\5dc75a9d6083a89858fc4557ff3a8969aec718d4.txt
```

This command response nothing. I checked with Notepad++,  5dc75a9d6083a89858fc4557ff3a8969aec718d4.txt file has UTF-8 and `Türkçe` string.
I checked `chcp` active code page 857. 857 is Turkish code.

When I was the call to findstr not Turkish character command response[image]
When I was check encoding with notepad ++, the file is utf8 encoding.
[image]

Will you help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: @JosefZ I try this. But not working on my code. Because I didn't see Turkish characters when I was call `type C:\wamp\www\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\text\5dc75a9d6083a89858fc4557ff3a8969aec718d4.txt`.

Comment: If the file contains UTF-8, the CP857 representation of the search string will obviously not be present in the file. The CP857 representation of the UTF-8 version of this string would appear to be `T├╝rk├ğe` (sic).

Comment: My search string converts to UTF-8 string but not working again.